# Elements Error with screens height above 768px

Tags: jquery, html, css

i had coded psd landing page to html5/css3 and make it fit ipad & mobile but there is a problem 
when i try browsing it in a screen with above 768px height the elements goes smaller and shows in the half page and the other half is just empty !! 
live url : http://idealogy-creative.com/1/
screen shot of the problem https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/c7f2884acf1102cc3536c1c5b8b62208ff8a8c92/win8.1_ie_11.0_Desktop.jpg

please help me please !

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues in Chrome 38 on the desktop

Comment: Please isolate the part causing problem and post the code in the question. It will help us helping you and also make this question more relevant for future readers.

Comment: the problem is not in some element its just fit fine with all landscape screens but in some portrait screens that use resolution like 1240x1024 it shows like the piture i posted above

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I changes something small to fix that, maybe viewport? Try to set viewport first and let me know, I'll check my websites.

P.S for Windows Phone you have to set some MORE things:
1. css

```
@-webkit-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-moz-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-o-viewport { width: device-width; }
@viewport { width: device-width; }
```

2. script:

   // fix for windows phone

   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/10.0/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/11.0/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/))
   {

   ```
   var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
   msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"));
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
   ```

   }

Comment: really thank yooou ! i also have windows phone problem and your code solve it ! ,, but for the rest it still nothing work even with viewport ..